# iOS - best practice to wait for protected data become available?

Tags: ios, core-data

i wonder if it's ok to defer app-start while protectedData isn't available ...

i mean something like

```
    while !UIApplication.shared.isProtectedDataAvailable {
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.05)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it’s not OK, `sleep` is the worst practice.

Don’t wait, there is the [protectedDataDidBecomeAvailableNotification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623039-protecteddatadidbecomeavailablen) notification

Comment: totally agree. but what's the best way to handle scenarios where you need to access database on app startup? enqueuing?

Comment: This **is** the best way. Observe the notification and run your code in the notification handler.

Comment: yepp, you're right. will take a while to refactor all the relevant codes and controllers, but in the end it makes sense. thx!